# Determining whether equation belongs to span

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm stuck on a textbook question where I'm asked to determine whether −x$^2$ + 2 belongs to span(−x$^2$ + x, x + 1) in P2(R).

I have the teacher's solution below but I don't understand where he got the values; -1, 0, and 2 from (as I circled below). I was wondering if someone could explain?

[image]

Comment: You need to put `$` signs around the MathJax commands for them to take effect.

Comment: Just comparing coefficients.  If two polynomials are equal, their difference is $0$, so the corresponding coefficients must be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for two polynomials to be equal, all of the matching coefficients must be equal. In your question, the x’s coefficient is 0 on the right and c1+c2 on the left, so in order for the equality to hold for all x, c1+c2=0. The other equations come from the x^2 and 1’s coefficients respectively.